# How to fix bless command can't access efi-boot-device in MacOS Recovery Mode?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

I run this command in Mac Recovery Mode via Terminal App

```
-bash-3.2# bless --info
Can't access "efi-boot-device" NVRAM variable
```

Comment: What version of macOS? Intel or Apple Silicon Mac?